iOS - Send message via Bluetooth SPP
I have a special Audio Device which can be connected to via Bluetooth like any other Headset or Headphone. Now the speciality for this Device is, it only starts sending its Audiostream, when it received a Message to its seperate Bluetooth SPP channel.
So to make this Audiodevice work, I would have to pair the device in the iOS Settings screen and after that, use a custom app to send a Message via Bluetooth SPP.
I have an android app which can do just that to open the Audio Stream, but is it also possible for iOS?
The CoreBluetooth Framework can only find BLE devices, so there is no chance to send or receive Messages to/from Bluetooth Classic devices. Is there an other way to do this?

No. There is no access to SPP on iOS. There is a similar protocol called IAP2 that is Apple-proprietary, but accessing it requires additional hardware on the Bluetooth device and MFi certification. (It is an expensive and paperwork-intensive process.)
